# spring jpa, findAll(Iterable<Integer> userIds)

Tags: performance, spring-data-jpa

findAll(ListU ..) in spring jpa is called by passing UUID's list  of size n, when  sql logs are enabled i found n number of sql getting logged ,which i assume DB is being called n times(size of list) to fetch records.

can it be possible to call DB only once to fetch all the records at once so that performance can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data uses an `IN` close for this method except when your entity has a composite key. That is already just one query.

So the multiple queries you see is most likely your JPA implementation deciding to return a proxy with just the id and then lazy loading the attributes by demand. See the documentation of the implementation you are using for how to prevent/control that.